# How to access a smart contract function protected by access rights using Web3?

Tags: tokens, contract-invocation, security, web3.py

I have a smart contract address for security tokens, and certain functions of it are protected by access rights, for which I have an address to access those functions, however I am not able to figure out, how to call that function by specifying the rights.

```
from web3 import HTTPProvider, Web3, exceptions

w3 = Web3(HTTPProvider('https://ropsten.infura.io/RPw9nHRS7Ue47RaKVvHM'))
contract_address = '0x635209612bf0e830ac348ef30357ee4f0e5bf560'
provider_abi =  [{"anonymous":False,"inputs":[{"indexed":False,"name":"addr","type":"address"},{"indexed":False,"name":"propertyKey","type":"bytes32"},{"indexed":False,"name":"propertyValue","type":"bytes32"}],"name":"PropertySet","type":"event"},{"constant":False,"inputs":[{"name":"_addr","type":"address"},{"name":"_propertyKey","type":"bytes32"},{"name":"_propertyValue","type":"bytes32"}],"name":"setProperty","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"bool"}],"payable":False,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":True,"inputs":[{"name":"_addr","type":"address"},{"name":"_propertyKey","type":"bytes32"}],"name":"getProperty","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"bytes32"}],"payable":False,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"}]

instance = w3.eth.contract(
    address=Web3.toChecksumAddress(contract_address),
    abi = provider_abi
)
user_address = "0x25BEADE120E501D7b984498D196eFe4AbE6a11F6"
country_key = "country"
country_byte_32 = Web3.toHex(Web3.toBytes(text=country_key))
print(country_byte_32) # Prints 0x636f756e747279
country_val = "IN"
country_val_byte_32 = Web3.toHex(Web3.toBytes(text=country_val))
print(country_val_byte_32) # Prints 0x494e
try:
    result = instance.call().setProperty(user_address,country_byte_32,country_val_byte_32)
    print(result) # Prints False
except exceptions.MismatchedABI as ve :
    print(ve)
    import traceback
    print(traceback.format_exc())
```

Can someone tell me, how do I provide the access right address?

Answer (score 3):

If you want to call a function of your contract by sending a new transaction, you have to use `myFunction.transact(transactionObject)`. The `transactionObject` is a dictionnary where you can specify the values for `value`, `gas`, `from`, etc...

Using `web3py 4.9.1`, it should be the following for your case : 
`instance.functions.setProperty(user_address,country_byte_32,country_val_byte_32).transact({"from":ACCOUNT CONTROLLED BY WEB3})`